# Not able to enable XNNPACK (TFLite) properly on Objective-C for ARM64 (Xcode 12.5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tensorflow-lite, accelerate, xcode12.5

Learnt that XNNPACK can accelerate computation a lot in general, thus tried on Xcode/Objective-C. Here's the imp according to official doc

```
// add XNNPACK
TFLInterpreterOptions *options = [[TFLInterpreterOptions alloc] init];
options.useXNNPACK = YES;
    
// init interpreter
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mymodel" ofType:@"tflite"];
_modelInterpreter = [[TFLInterpreter alloc] initWithModelPath:modelPath
                                                      options:options
                                                        error:&error];
```

With CocoaPods, I tried with TensorFlowLite 2.3.0, 2.4.0, and the latest x.x.x-nighly version. in all cases, whenever XNNPACK is enabled, the init fails. Internally it fails at this line in TFLInterpreter.mm:

```
_interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, cOptions);
```

Am I missing something or it's just XNNPACK is not properly implemented in the lib yet?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information of the failure? There are other reasons to fail at the TFLiteInterpreterCreate method, for example, invalid model argument and so on.

Comment: Error when logged is  ----    Error Domain=org.tensorflow.lite.interpreter Code=4 "Failed to create the interpreter." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create the interpreter.}, and just by setting option.useXNNPACK = NO, everything gets back to normal and the model runs fine. So far I can only assume it's this flag caused the failure

Comment: Could you upload this bug report at the TensorFlow github to invite more relevant folks?

Comment: no problem, will do

Comment: I don't suppose a link to the opened issue for those with the same problem is too much to ask for?